# Null serialization in Scala Play (implicit Writes)

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, implicit

I'm experimenting with Scala Play and don't get why Null json Serialization doesn't work out of the box. I wrote a simple class to encapsulate data in response (ServiceResponse) which return a parametrical nullable field `data` and also made a Writes[Null] implicit, what am I missing? The compiler suggests to write a Writes[ServiceResponse[Null]] which works, but feels cumbersome and I wonder if there is a more concise way of solving the problem. Below is the code and error.

```scala
// <!-- EDIT -->

// The data I want to transfer

case class Person (name: String, age: Int)

object Person {

  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Person = new Person(name, age)

  implicit val reader: Reads[Person] = Json.reads[Person]
  implicit val writer: OWrites[Person] = Json.writes[Person]

}


// <!-- END EDIT -->

case class ServiceResponse[T] (data: T, errorMessage: String, debugMessage: String)

object ServiceResponse {

  def apply[T](data: T, errorMessage: String, debugMessage: String): ServiceResponse[T] =
    new ServiceResponse(data, errorMessage, debugMessage)

  implicit def NullWriter: Writes[Null] = (_: Null) => JsNull

  implicit def writer[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]) = Json.writes[ServiceResponse[T]]

}

// <!-- EDIT -->

// Given the above code I would expect
// the call ` Json.toJson(ServiceResponse(null, "Error in deserializing json", null))`
// to produce the following Json: `{ "data": null, "errorMessage": "Error in deserializing json", "debugMessage": null }`
```

```
No Json serializer found for type models.ServiceResponse[Null]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

In C:\...\EchoController.scala:19
15    val wrapAndEcho = Action(parse.json) {
16      request =>
17        request.body.validate[Person] match {
18          case JsSuccess(p, _) => Ok(Json.toJson(echoService.wrapEcho(p)))
19          case JsError(errors) => BadRequest(Json.toJson(ServiceResponse(null, 
20            "Error in deserializing json", null)))
21        }
22    }
```

*EDIT*

Tried to use Option instead (a more Scala-ish solution, indeed) but the structure of the code is the same and reports the same error

```scala
object ServiceResponse {

  def apply[T](data: Option[T], errorMessage: Option[String], debugMessage: Option[String]): ServiceResponse[T] =
    new ServiceResponse(data, errorMessage, debugMessage)

  implicit def optionWriter[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]) = new Writes[Option[T]] {
    override def writes(o: Option[T]): JsValue = o match {
      case Some(value) => fmt.writes(value)
      case None => JsNull
    }
  }

  implicit def writer[T](implicit fmt: Writes[Option[T]]) = Json.writes[ServiceResponse[T]]

}
```

I think I need some structural change, but I can't figure what. Also tried changing the type of fmt to `Writes[T]` (being T the only real variable type) and got a new Error.

```
diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes[T1]
[error] starting with object StringWrites in trait DefaultWrites
[error]           case JsError(errors) => BadRequest(Json.toJson(ServiceResponse(None,
...
```

Thought I found a reasonable solution, but still getting error in the expansion of the implicit :( . I really need a hint.

```scala
object ServiceResponse {

  def apply[T](data: Option[T], errorMessage: Option[String], debugMessage: Option[String]): ServiceResponse[T] =
    new ServiceResponse(data, errorMessage, debugMessage)

  implicit def writer[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]): OWrites[ServiceResponse[T]] = (o: ServiceResponse[T]) => JsObject(
    Seq(
      ("data", o.data.map(fmt.writes).getOrElse(JsNull)),
      ("errorMessage", o.errorMessage.map(JsString).getOrElse(JsNull)),
      ("debugMessage", o.debugMessage.map(JsString).getOrElse(JsNull))
    )
  )
}
```

**NOTE**
I think I got the problem. Since null is a possible value of an instance of Person I was expecting it to be handled by Writes[Person]. The fact is that Writes is defined as invariant in its type paramater (it's `trait Writes[A]` not `trait Writes[+A]`) so `Writes[Null]` does not match the definition of the implicit parameter as would happen if it was defined as `Writes[+A]` (Which in turns would be wrong violating Liskow substitution principle; it could have been `Writes[-A]`, but this would have not solved the problem either, as we are trying to use the subtype Null of Person). Summing up: there is no shorter way to handle a ServiceResponse with a null data field than writing a specific implementation of `Writes[ServiceResponse[Null]]`, which is neither a super nor a sub type of `Write[ServiceResponse[Person]]`. (An approach could be a union type, but I think it's an overkill). 90% sure of my reasoning, correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Why would you use `Null` it can hardly make any sense therr

Comment: Build it with Option[T] as part of your JSON Models. It can ease things. And it will look neat.

Comment: @cchantep Null is the type of the null literal. Seemed sound to me.

Comment: `Null` is a workaround type, not a sound one, specially when working with type classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain it better, the ServiceResponse case class takes a type parameter T, which can be anything. And play-json can only provide JSON formats for standard scala types, for custom types you need to define the JSON formatter.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class ServiceResponse[T](
    data: T,
    errorMessage: Option[String],
    debugMessage: Option[String]
)

def format[T](implicit format: Format[T]) = Json.format[ServiceResponse[T]]

implicit val formatString = format[String]

val serviceResponseStr = ServiceResponse[String]("Hello", None, None)

val serviceResponseJsValue = Json.toJson(serviceResponseStr)

val fromString =
  Json.fromJson[ServiceResponse[String]](serviceResponseJsValue)

serviceResponseJsValue
fromString

serviceResponseJsValue.toString

Json.parse(serviceResponseJsValue.toString).as[ServiceResponse[String]]
```

In the above example, you can see that I wanted to create a ServiceResponse with data being a string, so I implement a format string which's necessary for Json.toJson, as well as Json.fromJson to have the readers and writers implemented for the type T. Since T being String and is a standard type, play-json by default is resolving the same.

I have added the scastie snippet, which will help you understand the same better, and you can play around with the same.

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/shankarshastri/spqJ1FQLS7ym1vm1ugDFEA/8.js"></script>
```

The above explanation suffices a use-case wherein in case of None, the key won't even be present as part of the json, but the question clearly calls out for having `key: null`, in case if data is not found.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val config =
  JsonConfiguration(optionHandlers = OptionHandlers.WritesNull)

case class ServiceResponse[T](
    data: Option[T],
    errorMessage: Option[String],
    debugMessage: Option[String]
)

def format[T](implicit format: Format[T]) = Json.format[ServiceResponse[T]]

implicit val formatString = format[String]

val serviceResponseStr = ServiceResponse[String](None, None, None)

val serviceResponseJsValue = Json.toJson(serviceResponseStr)

val fromString =
  Json.fromJson[ServiceResponse[String]](serviceResponseJsValue)

serviceResponseJsValue
fromString

serviceResponseJsValue.toString

Json.parse(serviceResponseJsValue.toString).as[ServiceResponse[String]]
```

Bringing the below line in the scope, will ensure to write nulls for optional.

```scala
implicit val config =
  JsonConfiguration(optionHandlers = OptionHandlers.WritesNull)
```

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/shankarshastri/rCUmEqXLTeuGqRNG6PPLpQ/6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you dedicated to answer me, still this miss the point: the actual value of T is not a standard Scala type (is my class Person) which has its  Writes[Person] implementation (`implicit val writer: OWrites[Person] = Json.writes[Person]`, in Person object) that still can't handle null values, not even with an ad-hoc writer (`NullWriter: Writes[Null] = (_: Null) => JsNull`). Reformulating the question isn't there a more concise way of handling ServiceResponse[Null] serialization than writing by hand an implementation of Writes[ServiceResponse[Null]] given that Person >: Null?

Comment: @ilmirons, so you meant you have a case where data is not present as well? can you explain the Json that you are expecting, adding it will help me think through, also please add the case class that you want, and compare the same with case class above that I have written.

Comment: @Shankar-Sastri : Did it. Notice I also added a note at the end of the question, think I got why it can not work as I did

Comment: @ilmirons, so you meant, you want to have null in the json response for the data is what you meant right?

Comment: Yes. And having `data` as an Option[T] as in the last snippet and serializing `None` as `null` would be even nicer (the problem remain the same)

Comment: @ilmirons, hope I have answered your question, I have updated the same based on your requirement, it can be achieved with the above :)